# Manter variável na memória até o reinicio do sistema

Tags: c#, .net, memória

Existe uma forma de manter uma variável na memória da maquina até seu reinicio?

Meu aplicativo fez uma alteração no sistema e enviei a mensagem para o usuário reiniciar a maquina, para prevenir qualquer problema eu tenho que detectar se a maquina já foi reiniciada mesmo que feche o programa e inicie novamente.

Imaginei que talvez pudesse usar criar um endereço na memória marcando que a maquina precisa reiniciar e armazenar nas configurações do aplicativo o endereço dessa variável, assim mesmo que reiniciassem o programa ele testaria se a posição na memória indica que precisa reiniciar...

Como tenho pouco conhecimento na área mais "baixo nível" do C# não sei se ele de fato armazenaria a variável ou se existe uma forma correta para tal.

Answer (score 7):

Marcus, como o Maniero apontou, não é possível manter uma variável em memoria, porém você pode salvar uma *flag* informando que o sistema precisa ser reiniciado, talvez a solução mais fácil seja alterar o `app.config`.

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
config.AppSettings.Settings["Restart"].Value = "true";
config.AppSettings.Settings["Data"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("o");
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

caso precise de mais dados, pode optar em armazenar um arquivo JSON em alguma pasta do sistema (o exemplo abaixo usa o [`Newtonsoft.Json`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)):

```
var dados = new { MustRestart = true, Data = DateTime.Now, Foo = "Hello", Bar = "World" };
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dados);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\dados.json", json);
```

Caso você tenha algum tipo de paranoia e deseje evitar que o usuario modifique estes valores, você tem duas opções, armazenar estes dados usando o Sqlite com SEE(SQLite Encryption Extension). você pode ver mais a respeito em.:

- [SQLite Encryption Extension](https://www.sqlite.org/see/doc/trunk/www/readme.wiki)
- [Dapper + SQLite](http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/sqlite-simple-database-with-dapper/)

por fim pode enviar uma requisição à uma `WebAPI` e esta vai atualizar uma `flag` informando que a maquina precisa ser reiniciada, esta abordagem tem dois pontos negativos, o cliente precisa de uma conexão com a internet e você precisa implementar e hospedar a `WebAPI`.

Quanto a saber se a maquina foi reiniciada, você pode ler os registros do Windows da seguinte forma, então bastará analisar as entradas.:

```
var eventLog = new System.Diagnostics.EventLog(); 
//eventLog.Source = ""; O ideal que informe o nome do Log que possui os eventos de inicialização do sistema.
foreach (var entry in eventLog.Entries) 
{
   Console.WriteLine(entry.Message);
}
```

Comment: irei da uma olhada, obrigado.
Eu estou atualmente utilizando esse recurso:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474293/how-to-programatically-find-out-the-last-login-time-to-a-machine
ele salva a data em um arquivo e se esta data permaneceu inalterado ele considera que ainda requer reinicialização, mas daria um falso positivo caso ele simplesmente saísse do usuário, mas não tenho tanta "paranóia" quanto a isso kkkkkkk, thanks ae amigo.

Answer (score 4):

Acho isso meio estranho, me parece que a solução para o problema até deveria ser outras. Mas respondendo a pergunta, não é possível nem em C#, nem em nenhuma linguagem manter dados da aplicação na memória quando ela não está sendo executada.

Mas pode obter o mesmo resultado mantendo dados em um arquivo. O que não tem nada de baixo nível.

Comment: é uma alteração na fonte do windows, como não sei forçar o windows recriar o cache das fontes mando o usuário reiniciar.
Eu imaginei que era possível manter uma variável na memória pois sempre vejo em C os códigos darem um tipo de Free(); imaginei então que talvez tendo o endereço na memória, talvez pudesse recuperar a variável mesmo com o fechamento do programa, mesmo que eu salvasse em um arquivo não tenho ideia de detectar se o sistema ja foi reiniciado desda ultima alteração.

Comment: talvez se existir algum valor temporário no windows que mude a cada inicialização do computador já seja uma forma de detectar...
Hmm, talvez o PID do processo System, sabe me informar se o mesmo processo tem em todas as versões do Windows (meu é win 10)?

Comment: Existe o registro do Windows. Mas isso é muita complicação. Então talvez você devesse fazer outra pergunta. Você achou uma solução esquisita para um problema que tinha e queria uma informação sobre isso. Seria melhor perguntar sobre o problema real e obter soluções melhores para alterar a fonte. Uma pergunta nova com detalhes sobre o que deseja pode ser mais produtivo para ter algo mais eficaz.

Comment: @MarcusAndré Nesse caso provavelmente é caso de outra pergunta mesmo. Instalação de fonte não precisa de reboot se fizer corretamente. Como é que está fazendo a tal instalação? Na verdade, uma aplicação bem feita simplesmente não mexe nas fontes do sistema. Tem problema em cima de problema aí. (o pior é que tem pessoal que usa fonte até pra código de barras, em vez de fazer pela aplicação). Fica a sugestão de, ao fazer uma nova pergunta, explicar nos mínimos detalhes.

Comment: @MarcusAndré Pra usar fonte sem fazer baderna no sistema do usuário: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: estou ciente que maioria das instalações das fontes não precisa reiniciar o sistema, acontece que meu caso é meio peculiar se trata de uma fonte protegida pelo windows na qual preciso modificar, no caso a MS Gothic e MS Meiryo, ja entrei em contato com a microsoft a melhor solução que eles conseguiram me arrumar foi o meu método atual que requer o reinicio da maquina para aplicar as alterações.

Comment: Aliás, a fonte eu de fato poderia carregar externamente, mas é como eu disse o caso aqui é meio peculiar não é meu programa quem vai ler a fonte e sim um certo jogo que só suporta caracteres SJIS, estou então fazendo uma modificação na fonte que tal jogo usa para poder colocar nossos caractéres (á é í ó ã ç), utilizando os half-width dos katakana/hiragana. logo creio que não haverá problemas.
Infelizmente o jogo tem um DRM e mesmo que não tivesse não sou lá essas coisas para tal façanha de trocar a encoding em que o jogo funciona.